# Tomcat 6.0.24 Exception: javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception

Tags: java, exception, resteasy, tomcat

I am using java RestEasy Framwork for my application. I have some exception when I am trying to make a requet in tomcat server.
Full stackTrace is:

```
Sep 26, 2011 1:50:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet my-servlet threw exception
java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2331)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1451)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1329)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator.getDefaultMapper(MapperConfigurator.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.locateMapper(JacksonJsonProvider.java:587)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:404)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:105)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.read(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:108)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.security.doseta.DigitalVerificationInterceptor.read(DigitalVerificationInterceptor.java:35)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:108)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:168)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:114)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:255)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:220)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:209)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:519)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:496)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception says that your servlet/JSP `extends` some other class, and that class is marked as final. Anyway, if it is a servlet (and not a JSP) that should have been detected at compile time.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But, The same code was running yesterday. And everything is same today as well. Still I have compiled it again and seen that everyclass is generated or not. There is one Info is displayed when I am starting tomcat it is : 
(\WEB-INF\lib\javaee.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

Is it the reason?

Comment: It might be some  incompatible jars stepping on each others toes. 

Try cleaning the .jar library folder of your application and the libraries of the tomcat (found in tomcat\lib).
As far as i know you don't need to include javaee.jar in your application of servlet-api.jar.

Comment: More than the servlet class itself, it looks like one of the classes being used by service(). Do you create any anonymous class there?

Comment: There is a class named @BadgerFish which I have used in Post method in Parameter to mapp with POJO. Everything is working if i dont Include this class in parameter.

Answer (score -1):

MAke sure the spring-expressions.jar exists in your tomcat libs directory... i had to copy it there (apart from copying it to my WEB-INF/libs) but doing the copy of that jar to my tomcat directory solved my similar problem